# Insert Statement has more column than Target Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

DB: SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition

I have to insert an XML content after splitting it in columns in a table using a Delta Load approach, sometimes the XML Content deliver 3 Column or 4 Columns,... the Insert is not possible because I don't know how many Columns will be delivered and I can't truncate the target table due to load performance.

Is there any way to insert data into a table without really knowing if more columns will be inserted then the table contains?

This is the way I load the data and to load the table `TAB_XML` incrementally

```
DECLARE @CrLf CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) , @tokenCounter INT , @i INT = 1;

SELECT  
    @tokenCounter = MAX(MESSDATA1.X1.value('count(KeyInfo)', 'INT'))
FROM 
    [TBL_FULL_DATA_XML] AS md 
CROSS APPLY 
    md.[ErgebnisMessung].nodes('/MDATA/DATA/DATAWrapper/Keys') AS MESSDATA1(X1)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '

INSERT INTO TAB_XML SELECT PE_ID, ';

WHILE @i <= @tokenCounter BEGIN SET @SQL += IIF(@i>1,', ','') + 'COALESCE(MESSDATA1.X1.value(''KeyInfo[' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(3)) + ']/@Name'', ''VARCHAR(30)''), '''') AS NAME' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(3)) + @CrLf SET @SQL += ', COALESCE(MESSDATA1.X1.value(''(KeyInfo[' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(3)) + ']/ValueString/text())[1]'', ''VARCHAR(30)''), '''') AS ValueString' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(3)) + @CrLf

SET @i += 1
END

SET @SQL += ', MESSDATA1.X1.value(''../MesswertName[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(200)'') AS MesswertName' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(3)) + @CrLf SET @SQL += ', MESSDATA1.X1.value(''../MesswertZahl[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(200)'') AS Messwert' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(3)) + @CrLf

SET @SQL += ' FROM [TBL_FULL_DATA_XML] AS md cross APPLY md.[ErgebnisMessung].nodes(''/MDATA/DATA/DATAWrapper/Keys'') AS MESSDATA1(X1);';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

the DLL of the Table has been created based on the First Load, but in Fact more Columns can be generated when another XML is loaded:

```
CREATE TABLE [TRANSFORM].[TBL__XML]( 
   [PE_ID] [bigint] NULL, 
   [NAME1] [varchar](30) NULL, 
   [ValueString1] [varchar](30) NULL, 
   [NAME2] [varchar](30) NULL, 
   [ValueString2] [varchar](30) NULL, 
   [NAME3] [varchar](30) NULL, 
   [ValueString3] [varchar](30) NULL, 
   [NAME4] [varchar](30) NULL, 
   [ValueString4] [varchar](30) NULL, 
   [MesswertName5] [nvarchar](200) NULL, 
   [Messwert5] [nvarchar](200) NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
```

the Version is Sql server 2017 Standard –

Comment: Pro Tip: Whenever constructing dynamic SQL, *always* PRINT out (or SELECT) your SQL string before executing it.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: MAK, it seems that you used my solution from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66698065/xml-nodes-with-sql It is very possible that you don't need dynamic SQL at all. Please provide ##1-4, as specified in my previous comment.